# Android Q - User remove in app settings persistent permission on uri. How to request permisson again?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, android-10.0

Android Q. I create file in android using Storage Access Framework(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) For example some image or video in Downloads directory. I use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT for this and after it I get persistent permission for this uri. As a result I get access for this file from my app after updating my application, restarting device. But user can go to system app settings and remove this permission. And after it I don't have access to this file by this Uri(for example I stored this Uri in database). But I need to show this image/video for user. How should I do it? How can I request permission for this Uri again? ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT doesn't support opening only one certain Uri?

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to have the user choose the document again via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. You are correct that you cannot force the user to choose this specific piece of content. But you are going to need `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` anyway, as the user can simply *move* the content, at which point your old `Uri` will no longer work. Clearing the permission strikes me as being less common than is moving or renaming the content, such that your old `Uri` is invalid.

Comment: How the user can remove the permission? Clearing app data? I didn't find any special button in the settings.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage#filtered-view) document:

> An app that has a filtered view always has read/write access to the files that it creates, both inside and outside its app-specific directory. Your app doesn't need to declare any storage permissions to access these files.

But we have a problem in Android Q that we cannot access a file by using raw path (create a File() instance with raw path or raw Uri), so we must access the file via `contentResolver`.

For your case, if you already created and saved the file Uri to your database, just use `context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(your-uri)` or `context.contentResolver.openInputStream(your-uri)`to access your file.

Comment: This is a painful and disgusting workflow!  If the user can easily revoke the write permission, why do we have to get permission every time?!  This is ridiculous in terms of user experience...  Users should be able to give blank check permission to any app they want without the need to ask every time just like before.